# Android using Linear layout maxWidth, not work with fill_parent

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

When using `fill_parent`, `maxWidth` has no effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:maxWidth="50dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The attribute `maxWidth` has no effect on a width of `match_parent` (or the deprecated `fill_parent`), they are mutually exclusive. You need to use `wrap_content`.

**Also** any layout that only has one child can probably be removed, for instance you can simplify you current layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:maxWidth="50dip"/>
```

Comment: Thank you! How to fill my EditText all width of the screen but not nore 500dip? For example some screen has resolution < 500.

Comment: This seems silly but it works: add `minWidth` and set both "min" and "max" to `500dp`.

Comment: @Sam - this doesnt seem to work for me, the editText still fills the entire screen except for the margins. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You can achieve the desired behaviour using a ConstraintLayout. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56060322/8302395).

Answer (score 30):

If anyone wants the combined behaviour of `match_parent` and `maxWidth` in a single parent layout: You can use a ConstraintLayout and 
constrain the child by the parent bounds combined with `layout_constraintWidth_max`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="480dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve the same effect using different layouts for different screens. Say you want your `EditText` to fill the available width but not more than 480dp. Difine your layouts as follows:

**layout/my_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**layout-w480dp/my_layout.xml:** (choose you max width as the qualifier here)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="480dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```