# how to make an EditText have a maximum width but still fill parent width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an EditText which I want to fill all the horizontal width available but the width should not be greater than 200dp

This makes EditText adapt to any screen size and still makes it look good on large screens (stretching horizontally won't look nice on a large screen).

How to do this in Android?

I saw that `maxWidth=200dp` and `layoutWidth=fill_parent` do not work together:

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/oldpassword"
           android:hint="@string/youroldpassword"
           android:inputType="textpassword"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:maxWidth="250dp" />
```

If `maxWidth` and `layoutWidth=fill_parent` do not work together, then what is the `maxWidth` meant for?

In other words, if the EditBox does not change its width dynamically, then what would you need `maxWidth` for?

Comment: Please add the whole layout so we can understand the purpose of this layouting..

Comment: its within a simple LinearLayout with layout_width and layout_height set to "fill_parent"

Comment: When you set maxWidth then width not exceeds given limit and When You set minWidth then it hold given limit even less or no content

Comment: If you want to EdiText fill rest of area then remove maxWidth properties from your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maxWidth doesn't work with fill\_parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325403/maxwidth-doesnt-work-with-fill-parent)

Answer (score 4):

you can set width programmatically depending on the device screen size.
like

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
if(width > 200)
{
    et.setWidth(200);
}
else
{
    et.setWidth(width);
}
```

Comment: I was afraid about that. Is this such an uncommon thing to achieve? Also, I am confused about what maxWidth is meant for. If it doesn't work with fill_parent, then what is it for?

Comment: as you require to set it dynamically so i thing not possible to work on xml files. ok still m trying for alternate option. wait...

Answer (score 2):

i have solution,
look if you set `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` it was always having it's width which have parent but when you set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` then it was increase size width with content while you entering Text in EditText, now if you use `android:maxWidth="250dp"` with `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` then it will increase it's width upto 250dp while entering value in EditText

use

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/oldpassword"
       android:hint="@string/youroldpassword"
       android:inputType="textpassword"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:maxWidth="250dp" />`
```

or use

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/oldpassword"
       android:hint="@string/youroldpassword"
       android:inputType="textpassword"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: I need something in between. I want the EditText to fill the parent but its width should not be over 250dp. But your explanation is useful, thanks

Comment: then you can define layout_width="250dp" fix other then no solution may be any one can help.

Answer (score 1):

remove  maxWidth=200dp in your layout

Comment: did you read my question? how can I make the EditText not stretch horizontally over 200dp?

Comment: post your layout file

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap edit text to relative layout.Here is what you can do -:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/oldpassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the editText in layout(which have width of 200dp) and make editText to match_parent.

Comment: what's the difference? the EditText width will be fixed to 200dp

Comment: Please refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325403/fill-parent-and-maxwidth-doesnt-work, look at the last answer's comments

Comment: it doesn't answer my question, the EditText is not stretched horizontally

Answer (score -3):

I solved it using **android:layout_marginRight="300dp"**, the greater is this value, the smaller is the width of the EditText object's line.

Comment: It's not the solution, because Android support 8000+ devices and 300 dp it's very big and you're layout should be very useless on some devices