# Relative Layout match parent and maximum width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a `RelativeLayout` and i want it to fill the whole width of the view, but if it would become bigger than `xx dip` it should stay in this size.
I tried to use `android:maxWidth="xxdp"` but it is not working with `match_parent`.

Comment: what's wrong with `android:layout_width="xxdip"` ?

Comment: then the layout is always xxdip and on smaller devices it is outside of the window instead of match_parent

Comment: with which attributes ?

Comment: to override width, I mean. You can have values/styles, and define width=xxdip but for smaller devices where do you define match_parent

Comment: k thats what i just did too, i was hoping for some more flexible solution, but i guess it will be fine, cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maxWidth doesn't work with fill\_parent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325403/maxwidth-doesnt-work-with-fill-parent)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Rather than setting width to `match_parent`, set the width to `"0dp"` and the weight of the layout to `1.0f`.
Assuming there are no other views in the same parent, this should force the `RelativeLayout` to fill the width. `maxWidth` should now work like you expected.

Comment: RelativeLayout ignores `layout_weight` attribute